# Can't add Synthetica look and feel to my java project

Tags: java

I'm using netbeans for my java project and I want to add synthetica look and feel to my project.

This is my code to set Synthetica look and feel

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();    

    try{
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaSilverMoonLookAndFeel());
        mf.setVisible(true);
        mf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I have already added `synthetica.jar` and `syntheticaSilverMoon.jar` to my libraries.

But when i'm trying to run the project it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/swing/plaf/synth/SynthUI
    at de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaDefaultLookup.getDefault(SyntheticaDefaultLookup.java:84)
    at sun.swing.DefaultLookup.get(DefaultLookup.java:125)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.getInputMap(BasicButtonListener.java:119)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.installKeyboardActions(BasicButtonListener.java:95)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.installKeyboardActions(BasicButtonUI.java:138)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.installUI(BasicButtonUI.java:90)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:666)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.setUI(AbstractButton.java:1810)
    at javax.swing.JButton.updateUI(JButton.java:147)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.init(AbstractButton.java:2176)
    at javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:137)
    at javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:91)
    at de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaLookAndFeel.installCompatibilityDefaults(SyntheticaLookAndFeel.java:553)
    at de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaLookAndFeel.access$4(SyntheticaLookAndFeel.java:405)
    at de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaLookAndFeel$2.propertyChange(SyntheticaLookAndFeel.java:313)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(SwingPropertyChangeSupport.java:92)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:548)
    at courseenrollmentsystem.CourseEnrollmentSystem.main(CourseEnrollmentSystem.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.swing.plaf.synth.SynthUI
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
```

What is the wrong with my code? Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems duplicate, looks like you are using old version of Synthetica which doesnt support latest JDK.Please download latest Synthetica which support latest JDK > 7. You can refer here to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614347/cant-access-synthetica-themes-on-new-netbeans-7-4-with-latest-jdk-1-7-0-45)